# Is there a way to correct this runtime error when using Protobuf-net and inheritance?

Tags: c#, inheritance, protobuf-net

Ok, I have the following code that used to work but now it does not. The only thing that changed is now I'm using VS2010 and .NET4

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(DerivedClass))]
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    protected virtual string MyString { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    [ProtoMember (2)]
    public readonly int SomeInt = 10;

    protected override string MyString
    {
        get { return "dummy"; }
        set { base.MyString = value; }
    }
}

[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var derived = new DerivedClass();


    using (Stream s = new MemoryStream ())
        Serializer.Serialize(s, derived);   // InvalidOperationException: Duplicate tag 2 detected in SomeInt
}
```

Is there something I am missing here?

I can see that PB is barfing on the same tag number for both classes when I override the parent property that uses the same tag number but I thought that would be isolated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will have to investigate - presumably some nuance of attributes and overrides - I don't know of a specific change, but that is... unexpected.

As a trial, you could add `[ProtoIgnore]` on the `override string MyString` - but please verify that it still serializes it (from the base-type)!

i.e.

```
[ProtoIgnore]
protected override string MyString
{
    get { return "dummy"; }
    set { base.MyString = value; }
}
```

For info, I've tested your code against v2, and it worked perfectly in VS2010 targeting .NET 4.0; I don't have v1 handy on this machine...

Comment: @Marc Yes, I'm using v1.0.0.282. I cannot find a download for V2 though.

Comment: @Stecy v2 is code-only at the moment; did ProtoIgnore do anything? You're more than welcome to try v2, simply: it isn't formally released

Comment: @Marc Regarding V2, do you have an estimate when it will be released? Is V2 usable in production right now? Are the serialization and deserialization produce the same result?

Comment: @Stecy - anything that differs is a bug; they are meant to be identical; simply: going through and checking every corner case takes effort. Also, some features (`GetProto()` etc) are still pending re-implementation - but I don't think you're using that

Comment: @Marc - You're right, I'm not using GetProto ;) Is this the only part of V2 not ready for prime time?

Comment: there are some other corner cases; the core serializer/deserializer is pretty solid, though. If you aren't sure, just use ProtoIgnore for now (if that fixes it)